# How to apply partial sort on a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lazy-evaluation, partial-sort

The following code:

```scala
val myDF = Seq(83, 90, 40, 94, 12, 70, 56, 70, 28, 91).toDF("number")
myDF.orderBy("number").limit(3).show
```

outputs:

```
+------+
|number|
+------+
|    12|
|    28|
|    40|
+------+
```

Does Spark's laziness in combination with the `limit` call and the implementation of `orderBy` automatically result in a [partially sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting) DataFrame, or are the remaining 7 numbers also sorted, even though it's not needed? And if so, is there a way to avoid this needless computational work?

---

Using `.explain()` shows, that two sorts stages are performed, first on each partition and then (with the top 3 each) a global one. But it does not state if these sorts are full or partial.

```scala
myDF.orderBy("number").limit(3).explain(true)
```

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 3
+- LocalLimit 3
   +- Sort [number#3416 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
      +- Project [value#3414 AS number#3416]
         +- LocalRelation [value#3414]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
number: int
GlobalLimit 3
+- LocalLimit 3
   +- Sort [number#3416 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
      +- Project [value#3414 AS number#3416]
         +- LocalRelation [value#3414]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 3
+- LocalLimit 3
   +- Sort [number#3416 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
      +- LocalRelation [number#3416]

== Physical Plan ==
TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=3, orderBy=[number#3416 ASC NULLS FIRST], output=[number#3416])
+- LocalTableScan [number#3416]
```

Comment: Probably related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195346/does-pyspark-changes-order-of-instructions-for-optimization

Answer (score 3):

If you `explain()` your dataframe, you'll find that Spark will first do a "local" sort within each partition, and then pick only top three elements from each for a final global sort before taking the top three out of it.

```
scala> myDF.orderBy("number").limit(3).explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 3
+- LocalLimit 3
   +- Sort [number#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
      +- Project [value#1 AS number#3]
         +- LocalRelation [value#1]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
number: int
GlobalLimit 3
+- LocalLimit 3
   +- Sort [number#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
      +- Project [value#1 AS number#3]
         +- LocalRelation [value#1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 3
+- LocalLimit 3
   +- Sort [number#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
      +- LocalRelation [number#3]

== Physical Plan ==
TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=3, orderBy=[number#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], output=[number#3])
+- LocalTableScan [number#3]
```

I think its best seen in the Optimized Logical Plan section, but physical says the same thing.

Comment: Nice, thanks. And do you know if the local sorts, and the final global one, are full or partial? (I've edited my question accordingly.)

Comment: Good question! I believe it uses Guava's TopK internally, so it should be partial. But looking at the source might be the only option if you want to be really sure :)

Comment: @abiratsis pointed to his great answer confirming this ^

Comment: Right, so on both levels (partial and final) no full sort is happening. That's good news! :)

Answer (score -1):

1. myDF.orderBy("number").limit(3).show
2. myDF.limit(3).orderBy("number").show

1 => will do full sort and then pick first 3 elements.

2 => will return dataframe with first 3 elements and sort.

Comment: I know. But that is now what I'm asking. ;)